# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named configs.Environment

Tags: python, fastapi, pipenv

I'm trying to run this project https://github.com/Progyan1997/fastapi-example
locally, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omar/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/omar/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/omar/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-tXminANK/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/home/omar/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-tXminANK/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/home/omar/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1501, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/home/omar/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-tXminANK/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/home/omar/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-tXminANK/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 458, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/home/omar/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-tXminANK/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/omar/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-tXminANK/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/home/omar/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/omar/Desktop/Learning/fastapi-example/./main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from configs.Environment import get_environment_variables
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'configs.Environment'
```

I have gone through the steps and installed Pipenv. But it still crashes with same error.

```
Python 3.8.13
pipenv, version 2022.5.2
```

Comment: Looks like typo in repo, try change `from configs.Environment` to `from configs.environment`.

Comment: @AlexeySherchenkov That was the issue indeed. Thanks a lot. Would you mind writing an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a typo in the repo, try changing `from configs.Environment` to `from configs.environment`
If it will help, please create PR to this repo, help opensource!

Comment: Yes of course. I let the author know.